# How to determine that a named tuple is a namedtuple object?

Tags: python, reflection

I have a predicate function that determines whether a dictionary (or in fact any `collections.abc.Mapping`) has the *shnudliwutz* characteristic.
Non-Mapping objects never have it.

Now I would like to extend the function so that it accepts named tuples (instances of `collections.namedtuple`-generated classes) as well and treats them like the corresponding dictionary.
But how do I recognize a named tuple?
The best solution I could find (in Python3) is shown below, but there sure must be a nicer one?

```
def is_shnudliwutz(mydict):
    if isinstance(mydict, tuple) and isinstance(mydict.__dict__, collections.abc.Mapping):
        mydict = mydict.__dict__  # treat named tuple like its dictionary
    if not isinstance(mydict, collections.abc.Mapping):
        return False
    ...  # now do your work
```

Comment: I had written up an answer to this, but since it's been closed I'll just note that on Python 2.x, `namedtuple`s do not have a `__dict__` attribute. Both 2.x and 3.x implementations, however, do have a "private" `_asdict()` method that returns a dictionary. You could check for that and call it.